# Unable to add a service reference to a mobile service project

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2015

When I try to add a service reference from Visual Studio 2015 to my Mobile Service Project, I`m getting this erro below:

[image]]

Message: The configuration for the service reference cold not be added due to the following issue: an error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/bindings - HRESULT: 0x800700057 (E_INVALIDARG)

This happens after "Add Service Reference" box:
[image]

Is there other way to include a service reference?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a service reference is nothing but generating the proxy class you can use of course svcutil from the visual studio command prompt

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:ProxyClass.cs /config:app.config http://YourserviceAdress
```

That should generate  a proxy class , just add it to your project and you'll be able to make calls to your service

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I resolved this issue in another way, I created a new solution from scratch and I tried again, so it worked.